# How can I count a decimal from every number of string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

In my problem I need to count every number in string with decimal (d), after I square `n` numbers. But, I don't know how I can do this. This is my code:

```
function nbDig(n, d) {
    let squareArr = [];
    let contor = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        squareArr.push(i * i);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < squareArr.length; i++) {
        while (squareArr[i]) {
            let lastDigit = squareArr[i] % 10;
            squareArr[i] /= 10;
            Math.floor(squareArr[i]);

            if (lastDigit === d) {
                contor++;
            }

        }
    }

    return contor;
}
```

Comment: Please provide an example of input and desired output.

Comment: Please explain a bit clearer. I don't understand what you mean by "count every number in string with decimal (d)"

Comment: Yes , my bad. I need to count every decimal who is identical with d. if i have n =10 and d=1, my squareArr wil be 0 ,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100 and contor will be 4(because of 1,16,81,100).

Comment: `Math.floor(squareArr[i]);` will not working

Comment: Can’t you just convert the number to a string and check if it contains the character `"1"`?

Comment: Is `d` always a single digit in [0-9]? Or can it be 21, 31, 99, etc?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function nbDig(n, d) {
    let squareArr = [];
    let counter = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        squareArr.push(i * i);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < squareArr.length; i++) {
        while (squareArr[i]) {
            let lastDigit = Math.floor(squareArr[i] % 10); // <- Updated
            squareArr[i] /= 10;
            squareArr[i] = Math.floor(squareArr[i]); // <- Updated ( Focus )
            if (lastDigit === d) {
                counter++;
            }

        }
    }

    return counter;
}
console.log(nbDig(10, 6))
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of just using an array that builds the squares of it's index, and then we use filter & String.includes to get those that have the digit in them, the length of this array will then be the count.

As an added bonus, if you comment out the `.length` it would then show you the numbers it found.

```js
const nbDig = (n, d) => 
  //create an array to loop over
  new Array(n+1).fill()
    //square the index
    .map((_,ix) => ix * ix)
    //filter out those with d
    .filter(f => f.toString().includes(d))
    //return length
    .length; 


console.log('nbDig(10, 1) = ' + nbDig(10, 1));
console.log('nbDig(20, 0) = ' + nbDig(20, 0));
```